# Add a Custom Payment Method to the Configuration Settings

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am looking to create a Custom Payment Method.  There are several tutorials online, and they all say that the system.xml and config.xml are the important files.  The command I used to install is:
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

I have used multiple versions of them, however none of them have shown up under the `Stores>Configuration>Sales>Payment Methods` menu.  What are the exact steps and magento 2 compile commands to install the custom payment method and get it installed so it is selectable?

Related Tutorials used:

https://ccbill.com/kb/magento-add-payment-method

https://magecomp.com/blog/create-custom-payment-method-in-magento-2/

Comment: do you want offline or Online (CC) payment method ?

Comment: You may have missed something. This methods work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Confirm you create the `required file` for the extension.

> ```
>  a. registration.php
>  b. module.xml
>  c. composer.json
> ```

2. Confirm also create the `system.xml` file properly and implement the
   `<section id="payment">` this.
3. Check you `install` the extension properly and that is `Enable` as well.

Comment: As it turns out, the curators of the website gave me the wrong server address.  This method works.